# Determine if video stream is a live stream

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

Is there a way to use `ffprobe` or `ffmpeg` to determine if a given stream (for instance `http://server/stream` or `rtmp://server/stream`...) is an on-going live stream or is fixed stream (i.e. recorded in the path with no live updates)?

Comment: Define "live". Does live mean that that what you are seeing happened within the last few seconds some place in space time? Or does it mean that every viewer is synchronized in some way? When you watch a TV show premiere, is it "live", even though to was recorded months earlier? Are reruns live?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the processing speed exceeds the stream framerate.

```
ffmpeg -i stream -f null -
```

Let it run for a minute or so.

You can also seek into the stream,

```
ffmpeg -ss 60 -i stream -preset superfast -t 5 test.mp4
```

For pre-recorded content, this should happen quicker than the seek duration, and the start should be the seek point requested. ffmpeg may start at the latest time available if the seek can't be exactly fulfilled.